# Vertical Scrollbar "Jumps" when trying to scroll down in a ListBox - C#

Tags: c#, listbox, scrollbar

I am currently making a simple Windows Form Application that compares two text files. The program loads each text file into a ListBox and then highlights their first difference. The only remaining issue I have pertains to the vertical scrollbar - every time you have a large text file (approx. 10000 pages) the scrollbar does not allow you to scroll to the end of the document (the scrollbar jumps back up to the top to no particular position every time). I believe this is due to my use of DrawItem to achieve the highlighting effect. Below are two snippets of code that should be enough for someone to point me in the right direction and if not, I will gladly post more. The first is the code for clicking the "Check" button that compares the two text files, and the second is the DrawItem:

First Code Snippet:

```
    private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        done = false;
        one = 0;
        two = 0;

        try
        {
            var file = File.OpenText(fone.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to open:" + fone.Text + ".");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var file2 = File.OpenText(ftwo.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to open:" + ftwo.Text + ".");
            return;
        }

        string[] msglines;

        msglines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fone.Text);

        foreach (string s in msglines)
        {
            foneBox.Items.Add(s);
            if (TextRenderer.MeasureText(s, myFont).Width > one)
            {
                one = TextRenderer.MeasureText(s, myFont).Width;
            }
        }

        foneBox.HorizontalExtent = one;

        string[] msglines2;

        msglines2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ftwo.Text);

        foreach (string s in msglines2)
        {
            ftwoBox.Items.Add(s);
            if (TextRenderer.MeasureText(s, myFont).Width > two)
            {
                two = TextRenderer.MeasureText(s, myFont).Width;
            }
        }

        ftwoBox.HorizontalExtent = two;
        int i = 0;

        if (foneBox.Items.Count == ftwoBox.Items.Count)
        {
            while (i < foneBox.Items.Count)
            {
                if (foneBox.Items[i].ToString() == ftwoBox.Items[i].ToString())
                {
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Files are not equal. The first difference has been highlighted.");
                    done = true;
                    index = i;
                    foneBox.SelectedIndex = i;
                    ftwoBox.SelectedIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
                if (i == foneBox.Items.Count && done==false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Files are equal.");
                }
            }
            i = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Files are not equal. The files are a different size.");
        }

        foneBox.Focus();
        ftwoBox.Focus();


    }
```

2nd Code Snippet:

```
    private void foneBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {

        myColor = Color.Black;
        myFont = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(myColor))
        {
            if (e.Index == index && done == true)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(foneBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont, brush, e.Bounds);
            }
            else
            {
                e.DrawBackground();
                e.Graphics.DrawString(foneBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That's a Windows bug.  Do not add more than 65535 items to a ListBox.

Comment: The solution is to create a custom text window or search online for one that provides the highlighting features you need.